How to flash (pulse) the entire line real-estate and not just till the end of the text?
I wrote something like this which I thought will work since it will include the newline.
(defun flash-current-line ()
  (interactive)
  (pulse-momentary-highlight-overlay
    (make-overlay
      (line-beginning-position)
      (+ (line-end-position) 1))))

It still only flashes till the end of the text on the line.
I know it is possible because the hl-line-mode does highlight the entire line as I describe.

This question is similar to: Showing markdown code background in "boxed" mode. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Probably M-x customize-group RET pulse and make those faces extend.

Here is what I ended up with,
(defun flash-current-line ()
  (interactive)
  (hl-line-mode 1)
  (run-with-timer 0.2 nil 'hl-line-mode 0))

